# Does discarding a value result in reading it?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Consider the following example:

```
{
  int x;
  (void)x; // silence the "unused" warning
  ...
}
```

Does this lead to undefined behavior due to `x` being read uninitialized? If yes, then does this mean that in the following code a memory read instruction (to read the pointee) must be emitted by the compiler?

```
volatile char* p=getP();
(void)*p;
```

I'm interested in both the C and C++ rules regarding this, in case they differ.

Comment: The only time I need to define a variable that's unused in C is when the variable is a parameter to a function and the function must satisfy an externally imposed interface (it will be called via a pointer to function, typically, and the interface for the set of pointers to function is fixed).  In that case, the parameter is initialized by the call mechanism, and there is no UB.  I can think of no other reason why I'd define `int x;` if it is unused.  (In C++, IIRC, you can define a function without a name for a parameter to indicate that the parameter is unused — so you don't need a cast.)

Comment: You need to clarify in which scope `x` is declared inside, or the question can't be answered. I'm assuming local scope?

Comment: @Lundin yes, in block scope. I.e. `x` is automatic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sometimes when you have `volatile const` variables in embedded system non-volatile memory,  you want to reserve space for them at a certain memory location, for future use. Even though the variables aren't used by the program (yet). Casting them to `void` somewhere can often trigger that the variable is getting linked and not just optimized out.

Comment: @Lundin: but in those circumstances, the definition and the void-use would not be on consecutive lines of code, I think.  Also, I don't code in embedded systems so the qualifier "the only time _I_ need to" remains accurate.  However, you're probably correct that there are circumstances where some people need to pull some funny stunts, but I suspect there'd be verbiage — comments and/or compiler-specific hints etc — around the declarations to make it clear what and why.

Comment: `(void)*(volatile int *)address` (or its equivalent) is sometimes used in embedded systems to fetch and discard a register, which itself can have effects like clearing flags (status/interrupt - fetching status / pending register in the interrupt prevents it from reocurring immediatelly, you can have interrupt for various errors, ignoring the specific type this way and re-setting the state). (I myself rather use method returning the value of the register - calling it but ignoring the result.)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, an *access* is coupled with a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. This conversion is what takes an "identity" and produces its value. On the subject of discarded value expressions, the C++ standard says this:

> **[expr]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#12) In some contexts, an expression only appears for its side
>   effects. Such an expression is called a discarded-value expression.
>   The array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer standard conversions are
>   not applied. **The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied if and only if
>   the expression is a glvalue of volatile-qualified type and it is one
>   of the following**:
>
> - ( expression ), where expression is one of these expressions,
> - id-expression,
> - subscripting,
> - class member access,
> - indirection,
> - pointer-to-member operation,
> - conditional expression where both the second and the third operands are one of these expressions, or
> - comma expression where the right operand is one of these expressions.
>
> [ Note: Using an overloaded operator causes a function call; the above
>   covers only operators with built-in meaning.  — end note ] If the
>   expression is a prvalue after this optional conversion, the temporary
>   materialization conversion is applied. [ Note: If the expression is an
>   lvalue of class type, it must have a volatile copy constructor to
>   initialize the temporary that is the result object of the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.  — end note ] The glvalue expression is
>   evaluated and its value is discarded.

In the non-volatile case, there is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. Therefore we can say with confidence the variable is *not accessed*.

In the volatile case however, you have indirection inside the cast-expression, and that undergoes a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. As such, the volatile *is* read, and you get undefined behavior out of reading an uninitialized object.

To avoid the undefined behavior around volatile glvalues, one can annotate the relevant variables as `[[maybe_unused]]`. That is the sanctioned way, and is the one I'd prefer over a cast in the non-volatile case too.

Comment: But what about C? It can't have the exact same rules since it doesn't have the extended _*value_ concepts that appeared in C++11 (although the wording might simply "flatten" them into the old ones). Also it doesn't have `[[maybe_unused]]` or any other attributes.

Comment: @Ruslan - See, this is the problem with double tagging. It becomes both too broad and to narrow to provide alternatives. I gave a C++ answer because it's more readily available to me. I'm looking for a normative reference for C, but someone may very well provide it first.

Comment: The quote also says "*The glvalue expression is evaluated and its value is discarded.*". Sounds contradictory to me. And what about [\[basic.life\]/7.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#7)?

Comment: @rustyx - The "glvalue" is evaluated, to produce an identity. And that is always discarded. The production of a "prvalue", the access, is conditional. And I implicitly assume from the OP that an object is there to speak of. Let's not drag [basic.life]/7 into this.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant part from the C standard:

> **6.3.2.2 void**
>
> The (nonexistent) value of a *void expression* (an expression that has type void) shall not
>   be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be
>   applied to such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void
>   expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its
>   side effects.)

Where *side-effects* are defined by 5.1.2.3/2:

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all *side effects*, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

Reading a non-volatile variable is not a side-effect.

That is, if accessing `x` is a side-effect, then the code must be evaluated (executed). This is only the case when `x` is `volatile`. So `(void)x;` will not trigger undefined behavior.

Otherwise it would have been undefined behavior to use the local variable `x`, because its address is never taken anywhere inside the scope.

In case of `*p` you have a clear lvalue access of a volatile-qualified variable through the `*` operator, so the compiler must read the variable. Regardless of the cast to `(void)`.

The example below would also be evaluated, but invokes undefined behavior (unless the address of the pointer `p` itself is taken):

```
char* volatile p;
(void)p;
```

Comment: _"So `(void)x;` will not trigger undefined behavior"_ doesn't seem to follow from the quote. Even if its value is discarded, `x` might still be read (or might not, due to the _as-if_ rule). Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ruslan No, "its value or designator is discarded". And since there are no side-effects, nothing gets evaluated. Side effects are formally defined as "Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
that does any of those operations". Added a clarification to the answer.

Comment: The `x` is `(void) x` is not a void expression. It is the operand of a cast to `void`. It is inside a void expression and is not the void expression. So 6.3.2.2 does not apply to it.